# How do I add POST /payments/:id/execute in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring-data-rest

In brief, I want to create these RESTful API endpoints

1. `POST /payments`
2. `GET  /payments/:id`
3. `POST /payments/:id/execute` => Charges the payer & changes the `status` to `executed`.

The `1st` and `2nd` endpoints can be achieved easily, but how do I implement the `3rd`?

Comment: How can `POST /payments/:id/execute` ever be RESTful?

Comment: @zeroflagL Actually, I follow PayPal REST API. Please look at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment. Also, Stripe does the similar thing https://stripe.com/docs/api#capture_charge. Both PayPal & Stripe claim their API is REST API

Comment: Thanks for the update, it makes more sense now. It's a, well,  interesting design choice. For me something like `POST /payments/:id/transactions` would make more sense. The solution looks rather like a service than a "regular" resource. That's why I think it would be better (and maybe easier) to create a controller for that action. To implement it with Spring Data REST you would need an independent `execute` resource afaik and that wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something other than CRUD operations with Spring Data REST, you'll need to use [Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) to [define a custom controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller). Your processing logic would go inside the controller, and you would handle any saving of resources yourself with a repository.

An alternative idea for something more spring-data-rest-style (and I haven't tested this) is to use Spring Data REST [events](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events). This hooks into the system directly and might allow you to do your extra work without defining your own controller/etc.

```
@RepositoryEventHandler 
public class TransactionEventHandler {

  @HandleBeforeSave
  public void handlePersonSave(Transaction incoming) {
    // call paypal, stripe, etc
    // flag incoming transaction as unsuccessful if the underlying transaction failed
  }
}
```